# Where to define a new role?

Tags: iccube

I need to insert a few new roles in **icCube**.

The doc mention I can monitor roles in the WEB user interface, but I could not find this option on the menus.

It mention I can also do it by editing the file **icCubeRoles.icc-roles**. However this file contains two roles: anonymous and standards, while the roles shown in the WEB interface when adding/editing a user are anonymous and standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature available in the Enterprise edition only. If you are using the Community edition and woud like to evaluate this feature please contact icCube directly to request an evaluation license.